# DB: map to another data model

Tags: java, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have 2 data models with different amount of tables in MySQL, but both designed for the same purpose.
I need to have mechanism which will migrate data from model #1 to model #2. It can be stored procedure, a set of SQL-scripts, or Java-code. 
It would be best to create mappings visually (e.g. drag from **Table1M1.field1** to **Table1M2.field5**). 
Is there any tool for this exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) has a [Database Migration](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) module. Check it out.